# Word to describe having to be neat and proper in a work email even though it's not that necessary?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know there's a word for it by my brain can't seem to find it. You know how we write our work emails to be all prim and proper even though we can get the message across in a more efficient way?

> We write these emails professionally for _____.

Something like "For the sake of it" but a level of importance higher.

Comment: Ritual? Tradition? Cargo cultism? Magical thinking? Neatness? Decorum? Manners? Politeness? Inertia? Conservatism? Retro sensibilities? Backwardness? History? Posterity? Defensiveness? Completeness? Filigree? Baroque? Rococo? Abstruseness? Stretching the point? Reductio ad absurdum? Punctiliousness? OCD? Amusement? Decoration? Civilised values? Preserving something of the old country? Empty ritual? Light relief? Professionalism?

Comment: Can I play too? brownie points, Hanukkah, the Gipper, auld lang syne, a reason, no reason in particular, the hell of it, ulterior motives, crying out loud, Pete's sake.

Answer (score 1):

**Propriety** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/propriety)) Correct language or pronunciation. [from 17th c.]
Suitability, fitness; the quality of being appropriate. [from 18th c.]
(often in the plural) Correctness in behaviour and morals; good manners, seemliness.

**Seemliness** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/seemliness)) (uncountable) The property of being seemly, appropriateness of conduct or behavior.
(countable) The result or product of being seemly.

Answer (score 0):

> We write these emails professionally for ***etiquette***.

It means

> the customary code of polite behaviour in society or among members of a particular profession or group. ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=etiquette%20meaning&oq=etiquette&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i433i512j46i175i199i512j0i512l3j46i175i199i512j0i512l3.3908j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))

> ***Etiquette*** is a set of customs and rules for polite behaviour, especially among a particular class of people or in a particular profession.
>
> - This was such a great breach of etiquette, he hardly knew what to do.([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/etiquette))

It is often preceded by an adjective or noun used attributively (*social/diplomatic/ business etiquette*, for example).